# Laravel 5 Generate ID and choose an random digit from the word with Value

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

It's possible with Laravel to make an text field where I can choose a random  digit from an before generated word and must enter to field, and if it's true the site redirect.

Example:

I have an word saved in my database like: `stackoverflow`

I visit my page and get a message like:

```
Choose the 3th Digit from your Word and enter it
```

The correct answer is `a` in this example. If I enter it in the text input field and Laravel check it if it's correct and if its true i redirect to homepage.

It's also possible in Laravel to change always if i visit the page the Digit i must choose like: Choose `3th Digit,1th Digit,6th Digit`

Many Thanks

Comment: Is it suppose to be a kind of captcha? That's a simple php code. Nobody is going to write the whole code for you.. What did you try so far?

Comment: Not captcha, For example i have an mnemonic  word list and they must validate by enter missing words after copying

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if that could help

```
$string = 'stackoverflow';
$find   = 'a';
$position = strpos($string, $find);

// Note our use of ===.  Simply == would not work as expected
// because the position of 'a' was the 0th (first) character.
if ($position === false) {
    echo "The string '$find' was not found in the string '$string'";
} else {
    echo "The string '$find' was found in the string '$string'";
    echo " and exists at position $position";
}
```

Reference: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php

Comment: Looks great,can i also make it random where must find always an other digit if the site are visit?

Comment: Can you explain it further, please?

Comment: always an other " $find   = 'a'; " when i reload the page, like sometimes "a" then "s"

Comment: You just have to replace the value passed to the variable `$find` with the data you want.

Comment: For example if you are passing the character to search to the URL (http://example.com?character=s). You just have to replace " $find = 'a'; "  by " $find = request('character'); ". Laravel provides the helper function [request()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/helpers#method-request) to get all the passed data

Answer (score 0):

I will write a basic pseudo code, you can write it and improve it in php.
Let's assume you have a string with X characters.

1. Randomize a number between 1 and X, let's call it N.
2. Remove the Nth character from the given string and replace with underscore or something.
3. Ask the user to enter the Nth character.
4. Check if the input was the Nth character you removed.
5. Redirect if true, show error if false.